# How to cancel a NSPrintOperation

Tags: swift, macos, nsprintoperation

Is it possible to cancel an already running NSPrintOperation? I have the following code:

```
let printOp: NSPrintOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: ..., printInfo: ...)
printOp.jobTitle = "Custom Print"
printOp.showsPrintPanel = false
printOp.showsProgressPanel = false
printOp.canSpawnSeparateThread = true
printOp.run()
```

I see there's a NSPrintInfo jobDisposition of .cancel but I don't know how I would apply that to an existing task thats running. You're able to do it in the printer job queue in macOS but I can't find a way to do it in code.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to cancel the print operation but from where do you want to cancel?

Comment: I’m not using a print panel. It’s all print command in swift code. If you open the printer queue in system preferences, you can delete jobs there - but I want that ability in my app.

Comment: Do you want to cancel the print operation while it is running or do you want to remove a completed print operation from the queue?

Comment: Cancel a currently running operation. So say my app sent out 30 print commands, I want a way to cancel one (or all) of the currently running jobs.

Comment: Do you run 30 print operations simultaniously? It is possible to cancel a running print opereration with (the Swift equivalent of) `NSPrintOperation.currentOperation.printInfo.jobDisposition = NSPrintCancelJob;`. It is not possible to cancel a finished operation.

Comment: Yeah.. I send a lot of batch prints. How does macOS do it then? In the printer jobs app I’m able to see all pending jobs and delete all of them.

Comment: Your question is How to cancel `printOp.run()` ("incoming" in the queue). Please ask a new question How to remove pending print jobs ("printing" in the queue).